# What is the meaning of colorbar.solids in Pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating contour plots with matplotlib/pyplot and trying to print out a customized colorbar as well. I am also attempting to have the colorbar be printed in a completely separate image file from the plot.

```
        sub_fig = plt.figure()
        sub_ax = plt.axes()
        sub_ax.axis("off")
        #cs2 is a contourf object
        sep_cb = plt.colorbar(cs2, cax=sub_ax)#, cax = new_figure.legend, ax=new_figure.legend, orientation="vertical")
        sep_cb.shrink=0.5
        sep_cb.fraction=.1
        sep_cb.drawedges=True
        # ~sep_cb.solids.set_edgecolor("white")
        plt.savefig("colorbar_"+str(ii)+".png")
        plt.clf()
```

So I am referring to the documentation here: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html but I find that changing the settings does not change the appearance of my colorbar. What I want is actually to make it pretty small, and have the sections separated by some whitespace, with the values/ labels to the right. I can't shrink it, or make the values appear. No matter what, it appears like this:

[colorbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qqAn.png)

However, if I enable that sep_cb.solids line, I get some lines between the sections. But the only reason I even know about this is because of this section:

> It is known that some vector graphics viewer (svg and pdf) renders white gaps between segments of the colorbar. This is due to bugs in the viewers not matplotlib. As a workaround the colorbar can be rendered with overlapping segments:

```
cbar = colorbar()
cbar.solids.set_edgecolor("face")
draw()
```

It seems that colorbar.solids can be used to set some options on the plot, but I cannot find any documentation on that directly, I don't even see it mentioned elsewhere on the page. Is this some basic pyplot thing I have managed to overlook? Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why do you try to set the attributes of the colorbar instead of just passing the keywords, i.e. `plt.colorbar(cs2, cax=sub_ax, shrink=0.5, fraction=0.1, drawedges=True)`? Note that you should only set one axes argument -- either `ax` or `cax`. If I understand your intentions correctly, it should be `cax` for you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, perhaps I should have been more thorough about what I have tried, but I have done all of that, and double checked just now, none of it makes any difference in my output. You are right that it should just be cax, again I was just trying options there to see if anything would happen. I will edit that in the question, though.

Comment: It's not too clear what you are trying to achieve. I understand you want a smaller colorbar. So either put it in a smaller figure (`figsize=(..)`) or create a smaller axes inside the large figure (`.axes([left, bottom, width, height])`). To create lines in your axes you can use `ax.plot`, or `ax.hlines`.